Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js'
i recently installed nodejs on my laptop running on win 11 . node -v ran perfectly . but tried running the script npm --version its showing this error
PS C:\Users\saikat mandal> node
Welcome to Node.js v22.3.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
(To exit, press Ctrl+C again or Ctrl+D or type .exit)
>
PS C:\Users\saikat mandal> npm
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1215
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1038:27)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v22.3.0

Could not determine Node.js install directory
please help me to find solutions to it
tried running npm but its shows me error.
